# Google Map Accuracy Radius

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils, mylocationoverlay

I use Google Maps for my project. It shows approximate location on a map, surrounded by a blue circle showing the inaccuracy of your position. 
I want to understand how correctly determined my location. And the question is how to get the radius of this accuracy circle?

[image]

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your questions by providing your exact requirements or some block of codes? Thanks

Comment: @BasitAli, I supplemented my question

Answer (score 2):

Location.getAccuracy() - the value of the radius of blue circle.

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener` was the way of what the blue dot shows. It was receiving location and you were able get accuracy but it's deprecated.

Google suggests [`FusedLocationProviderApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener) instead. It's also source of blue dot

> Use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot.